# How to read registry resource string e.g. "@filename,resource"?

Tags: windows, winapi

I have a registry entry e.g. `LocalizedString=@%programfiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe,-702`
Is there a known API to extract the path and the string other than custom-ally parse it (and use `LoadString`)?

And then I have a defult value e.g. `(default)="%programfiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"` (including the double-quotes, but without the `@`);

How does Windows handle this stuff?

Comment: Check out this page - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374120

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The API function you need is called [RegLoadMUIStringW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724890.aspx). This is a Vista API so if you want to support XP you'll need to parse the registry entry manually.

**Update**: Actually, [SHLoadIndirectString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb759919.aspx) looks like it could be your XP saviour.

Comment: brilliant. thanks! any tip on the "default" value? is there an API for that monster?

Comment: I mean, how to translate `"%programfiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"` to `c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe`

Comment: [`ExpandEnvironmentStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724265.aspx)

Comment: Yes, `SHLoadIndirectString` is precisely what I'd recommend. Related reading: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2007/10/31/5790802.aspx